# addClass('open') is not working in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am facing some weird problem. i am trying to add **"open"** class on certain condition. I am using following code.

```
 $('.stereo-nav-pos .login-register').addClass("open");
```

but its not working. I have tried to debug and i came to know that actually its appending **"open"** class and then its going to jquery.js file,at the end of jquery.js execution its removing **"open"** class from DOM.

then i have tried to add class called **"openn"** and it worked fine. So i am figuring out the issue why jquery.js file is remove **"open"** class from DOM?

If i try to run this code in console then its working fine.

can anyone tell me what's going wrong here?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have any other jQuery plugins in your page? This may for example be removing the open-class and thus conflicting with your code. Try to disable other plugins temporarily (by removing it) to see if that helps.

Comment: If at the end of js file, class is getting removed then definitely somewhere in your code you have removeClass function being called.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for you or not, I had encountered similar problem a while ago.
What I've done is that I used `setTimeout()`.

So you may try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
   $('.stereo-nav-pos .login-register').addClass("open"); 
},10);
```

This will let the function to add the class `open` after a while so that it doesn't gets removed by the other jQuery function.

Answer (score 0):

Adding class "open" works just fine.

Try to see if your selector selects anything

```
console.log("test",$('.stereo-nav-pos .login-register').length);
```

Check this jsfiddle test.
http://jsfiddle.net/ja4xapdg/

Answer (score 0):

Tested it and it seems to work just fine for me, there must be something different that causes this problem to occur.

`Result if it doesn't work: red background`

`Result if it does work: green background`

http://jsfiddle.net/mnbtnk7h/